# NameError: uninitialized constant in Rails app when attempting to import CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, activerecord

I am making a rails application which relies on a database based on a CSV file that I got from scraping a site. I want to import the CVS file into the database. I generated a model as seen below.

```
class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

And my migrate file:

```
    class CreateChallenges < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :challenges do |t|
      t.string :location
      t.string :name_source
      t.string :location_name
      t.string :name_text
      t.string :restaurant_text
      t.string :restaurant
      t.string :location_title
      t.string :description
      t.string :name
      t.string :state

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

And my Rakefile:

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
require 'csv'
require 'Models::Challenge.rb'

Rails.application.load_tasks

csv_text = File.read('db/Vancouver.csv', :encoding => 'iso-8859-1')
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
csv.each do |row|
  Challenge.create!(row)
end
```

When I run `rake import` or `bundle exec rake import:challenge` I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- Models::Challenge.rb
/Users/kamilkhan/Documents/CPSC 310/Project/Rubies-In-The-Rough/Rakefile:6:in `require'
/Users/kamilkhan/Documents/CPSC 310/Project/Rubies-In-The-Rough/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

--trace gives me:

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- Models::Challenge.rb
/Users/kamilkhan/Documents/CPSC 310/Project/Rubies-In-The-Rough/Rakefile:6:in `require'
/Users/kamilkhan/Documents/CPSC 310/Project/Rubies-In-The-Rough/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/kamilkhan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/Users/kamilkhan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/kamilkhan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/kamilkhan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/kamilkhan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/kamilkhan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/kamilkhan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/Users/kamilkhan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/kamilkhan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/kamilkhan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas as to how to fix this? I am quite new to Ruby and Rails so please ELI5

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rake can automatically loads all your models etc. for you.  Additionally, you should put that task into its own file, not the Rakefile that rails uses.

Try something like this:

**lib/tasks/import.rake** (any file name ending with .rake will work)

```
desc "Imports stuff from CSV"
task :import => :environment do
  require 'csv'

  csv_text = File.read('db/Vancouver.csv', :encoding => 'iso-8859-1')
  csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
  csv.each do |row|
    Challenge.create!(row)
  end
end
```

You should then be able to run `rake import` to run that task.  `environment` tells rake to load up your Rails stack so you can use your models etc.